# Should instruments always weakly increase standard errors?

Tags: standard-error, instrumental-variables, clustered-standard-errors, 2sls, robust-standard-error

In OLS, are standard error estimates using some instrument $z$, different from $x$ always weakly larger than standard errors when not using instruments? This has been discussed before: [Why is the variance of 2SLS bigger than that of OLS?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242762/why-is-the-variance-of-2sls-bigger-than-that-of-ols?rq=1)

But does it make a difference when one uses robust or clustered standard errors?