# Are standard errors from a second stage with OLS always underestimated?

Tags: standard-error, stata, instrumental-variables, 2sls

I use Stata. I build on [Standard errors of a two stage least squares regression, Stata](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126313/standard-errors-of-a-two-stage-least-squares-regression-stata?noredirect=1&lq=1) to compute manually the standard errors for my model:

- I cannot use standard packages (ivreg2 etc.) as the second stage is estimated on the whole data while the first stage is estimated on a subset of the data, a feature that standard packages do not handle.
- The main difference with the example from the link is that I use a FE model with clustered standard errors.

The standard errors I obtain after manual correction are smaller than the ones I would obtain in the second stage from "naive" OLS. This does not seem correct. I remembered from econometrics class that naive OLS does not take into account that the fitted values used in the second stage are themselves estimated and therefore necessarily underestimates the standard errors. In the best case where you perfectly model the endogenous regressor in the first stage (for example if it can be used as an instrument for itself, i.e. it is exogenous), then you are simply back to the OLS case but in no circumstances can beat it.

From this intuition, I tend not to believe my calculations for correct SE.

Am I right to be suspicious? In a quick literature review, I could find textbook references stating in a nutshell that "SE from OLS are wrong" (see below), but I could not find explicitly that they are always underestimated.

**EDIT 1: more on "SE from OLS are wrong"**

> Another reason to avoid the two-step procedure is that the **OLS standard errors reported with regression (5.19) will be incorrect**, something that will become clear later

p. 91 in Wooldridge: Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data, available at https://ipcig.org/evaluation/apoio/Wooldridge%20-%20Cross-section%20and%20Panel%20Data.pdf

or here again

> Most econometrics packages have special commands for 2SLS, so there is no need to perform the two stages explicitly. In fact, in most cases you should avoid doing the second stage manually, **as the standard errors and test statistics obtained in this way are not valid**. [The reason is that the error term in (15.39) includes v2, but the standard errors involve the variance of u1 only.]

p. 529 in Wooldridge: Introductory Econometrics A Modern Approach (available at https://economics.ut.ac.ir/documents/3030266/14100645/Jeffrey_M._Wooldridge_Introductory_Econometrics_A_Modern_Approach__2012.pdf)

Comment: Is it worth considering a difference between always being underestimated and always being biased low?

Comment: Are you sure the answer in the linked thread requires OLS to be BLUE? It seems to me the linear algebra of the proof goes through regardless.

Comment: Christoph Hanck has edited his answer, and the quote in EDIT 2 is no longer there. Perhaps that thread does apply to your situation after all.

Comment: Thank you Richard for both comments. I think you're right, the proof does not require OLS to be BLUE and my question is indeed a duplicate. I have been able to move along with my piece of code and find out the issue such that practice and theory don't contradict anymore.

Comment: @axel365, sounds great!